# Is there a way to select Editions when playing MKV files on Android?

Tags: video, media-player

MKV video files have a feature called [editions](https://www.matroska.org/technical/chapters.html), which allows you to string together multiple chapters into a sort of playlist all within one file. For example, a single file could contain the chapters for the extended cut of a movie, and an extended edition and theatrical edition that selectively include those chapters.

On Android I have tried two video players, VLC and MKV. I can't figure out how to choose an edition to play in either of these. Is there any way to play an MKV file on android and be able to select an edition to play, before or during playback of a file?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. Do these edits make it sufficiently broad?

Comment: That should be fine, thanks. P.S. you might want to edit the title to reflect the issue you want to solve too :)

Comment: So I was able to find a repo with different forms/features of MKV files: https://github.com/hubblec4/Matroska-Playback/tree/master/files And I think what you want is similar to OrderedChapters ('Title' in Playback menu on VLC for PC) but given the lack of discussion I've been able to find about it may be a low priority item for media app developers/lack of user feature request.